Expected value of a transformed variable.
I'm new to probability and I want to know the general formula for calculating the mean and variance of a transformed random variable.
Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with distribution function $f(x)$ and a one-to-one function $h(x)=y$. Define another continuous random variable $Y = h(X)$, the distribution function of $Y$ is:
$$
g(y)=f(h^{-1}(y))|(h^{-1})'(y)|
$$
Then is $E[h(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x)f(x)dx $ equal $E[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y\,g(y)dy$. Or in other words under the condition above, can we prove that:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x)f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(h^{-1}(x))|(h^{-1})'(x)|dx
$$
If yes then what is the proof  of this problem and does the same goes for the variance? I have tried searching and proving it myself but I can't figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.

Let me give you some basic ideas so you can do the proof yourself. The proof relies on a change of variable formula. Suppose I do the following change of variable: $h(x) = z$. Then $x = h^{-1}(z)$. We also have
$$
dx = \frac{d}{dz} h^{-1}(z) = (h^{-1})'(z) dz \,.
$$
Now, use this in your integral. You had,
$$
\int h(x) f(x) \ dx \,.
$$
We now perform the change of variable: $z \leftarrow h(x)$ and $dx \leftarrow (h^{-1})'(z) \ dz$. Then we have:
$$
\int h(x) f(x) \ dx = \int z f(h^{-1}(z))(h^{-1})'(z) \ dz \,.
$$
So far, it is almost your expression, $\textbf{except}$ the modulus, i.e. we obtained $(h^{-1})'(z)$ instead of $|(h^{-1})'(z)|$. I am leaving this for you to think about and play with some functions $h$.
$\textbf{Hint}$: This concerns the orientation. So far, we have not talked about the limits of the integral. As we are substituting $h(x) = z$, then the limits of integral should be $h(-\infty)$ and $h(\infty)$. If $h$ is a decreasing function, i.e., say $h(x) = -x$. Then $h(-\infty) = \infty$ and $h(\infty) = -\infty$. So the new integral is from $\infty$ to $-\infty$ and $(h^{-1})'(x)$ is negative (as $h^{-1}$ is also decreasing). So we can change the sign of $(h^{-1})'$ and change the limits of the integral.
